# Compact Framework Unit Testing via Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

Tags: .net, unit-testing, compact-framework

I want to write Unit Test suite for my .netcf 3.5 C# application and I want it to run on device. How do I setup to do this? I am using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.

Comment: So what's the question?  Create a Unit Test project, write a unit test and run it.

Answer (score 0):

I've personally had no problem unit testing with NUnit when targeting .NetCF 3.5. There may be some limitations but i haven't come across them yet.

Comment: But did the test run on the Device?

Comment: He's not asking about NUnit (which doesn't run the test on the device) but mstest (which does)